# Extracting only message content from Javamail API msg.getContent()

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

What should I write for extracting only the text from the msg.getContent() to get the exact text instead of HTML code?

If anyone can assist me with the regex part or any method to extract the content it would be great!

```java
class ReceiveMail extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //create session object
        Session session = this.getImapSession();
        String messageContent = "";
        try {
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, username, password);
            IMAPFolder inbox = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
            for (Message msg : messages) {
                try {
                    int j = messages.length - 1;
                    fromAddress = msg.getFrom();
                    from = fromAddress[0].toString();
                    subject = msg.getSubject();
                    toList = msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO);
                    ccList = msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC);
                    content = msg.getContent().toString();
                    Object msgContent = msg.getContent();
                    
                    if (msgContent instanceof Multipart) {

                        Multipart multipart = (Multipart) msgContent;

                        for (int k = 0; k < multipart.getCount(); k++) {

                            BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(k);

                            String disposition = bodyPart.getDisposition();

                            if (disposition != null && (disposition.equalsIgnoreCase("ATTACHMENT"))) {
                                System.out.println("Mail have some attachment");

                                DataHandler handler = bodyPart.getDataHandler();
                                System.out.println("file name : " + handler.getName());
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Content: " + bodyPart.getContent());
                                content = bodyPart.getContent().toString();
                                System.out.println("Content: " + bodyPart.getContent());
                                //content = messages[i].getContent().toString();
                            }
                        }
                    } else
                        content = msg.getContent().toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Please clarify your problem, and why you think you need a regex for this. This is a matter of calling `getContent()` on the right part. See also the JakartaMail FAQ, ["How do I find the main message body in a message that has attachments?"](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/FAQ.html#mainbody). Also notice how that lookup is recursive, because a MIME message structure can be more complex than what your code assumes it to be.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31413048/extract-only-text-part-of-email-body-using-javamail-without-html-content may help

Comment: Someone who has done programming in java recommended me to use regex, for extracting text from html, but i want to use jsoup parser for extracting it, can anyone tell me the code to extract using that?