# Java mail - Retrieve links url from a javax.mail.Message which is a multipart

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, pop3

Let's say I have an email which is a mimeMultipart, and contains one or more links. So at a certain point I got this javax.mail.Message, and by now all I was able to do is get the plain text.

```
private static String parseContent(Message m) throws Exception  {

    Object content = m.getContent();
    String contentReturn = null;

    if (content instanceof String) {
        contentReturn = (String) content;
    } else if (content instanceof Multipart) {
        Multipart multipart = (Multipart) content;
        BodyPart part = multipart.getBodyPart(0);
        contentReturn = part.getContent().toString();

    }   
    return contentReturn;
}
```

Is it possible (maybe with some "get methode" I ignore on Message object, or maybe using javascript) to retrieve all the url of the links?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read html body of an email using javamail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212534/read-html-body-of-an-email-using-javamail)

Comment: Can you post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?