# Outlook message files to image/HTML using java

Tags: java, html, image, outlook, message

Could you please provide some input on the open source libraries to convert an outlook message into HTML or image. The outlook mail style should be preserved. We initially tried for the paid library Aspose, but due to budget constraints, the client is asking for open source. Whether this is achievable using Java?

Regards
Sam

Answer (score 1):

Most of the e-mail messages are already have HTML mail part inside (if they don't text part will be present). What you need is to retrieve the HTML part from the message. [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) framework will help you to do this. There are plenty of examples on how to retrieve HTML part from a message. One of them is [read html body of an email using javamail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212534/read-html-body-of-an-email-using-javamail). This is how you'll get HTML. Another story is to convert this HTML into the image. I believe simple search will provide you with examples as well. One of them is [java-html2image](https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-html2image/).